# how to handle the click event to display text in the <span> tag on reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to send the contents of the text box to be displayed in the spam when I click on the button

```
class Hello extends Component {

    state = {
        texto: ""
    }

    changeText = () =>{
        this.setState({texto: this.state.texto})
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input type = "text" defaultValue = {this.state.texto}></input>  
                <p>{this.state.texto}</p>
                <button onClick = {this.changeText}>Click</button>              
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Hello;


function App() {  
  return (     
    <div>
     <Hello />
    </div>     
  );
}
```

The idea is that when you click on the button it shows the ones in the text box inside the span.

I am new to react and this clarifies some doubts about the concepts.
thanks guys.

Comment: Where is the span? I only see input, p, and button elements/tags. And what problem are you encountering?

Comment: I'd take a look at the docs on [controlled inputs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components)

Answer (score 0):

Carlos!

First of all, you must update your input so your code can work properly. In your input, do this instead:

```
<input type="text" value={this.state.texto} onChange={() => this.onChangeHandler(e.target.value)}></input>
```

Then, inside your class, you create an onChangeHandler to deal with the data from input first:

onChangeHandler = (e) =>  {
     this.setState({
    texto: e
    });
    }

Ok, we're almost there, now you must create another state item, so you can use it for your final input:

```
state = {
    texto: "",
textoFinished: ""
}
```

Then, correct your onChange envent:

```
changeText = () =>{
    this.setState({textoFinished: this.state.texto})
}
```

Now, to access the new value, just go to `this.state.textoFinished`. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the state using target value after clicking on it.

Something Like this :

```
state = {
  texto: ""
}

onChangeHandler = (e) => {
  const value = e.target.value;
  this.setState({texto: value});
}

OR

onChangeHandler = (e) => {
  const texto = e.target.value;
  this.setState({texto});
}
```